# rails transaction specific timeout?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to add a timeout for transactions? I'd like to [avoid ruby's timeout.](http://www.mikeperham.com/2015/05/08/timeout-rubys-most-dangerous-api/)

I'd like to do something like:

```
Listing.transaction(timeout: 1.seconds) do 
  Delayed::Job.enqueue(RecentListingsJob.new(user.id, @listing.id))
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to raise an exception for a timeout, you could use Ruby's Timeout. Here's the [doc](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/timeout/rdoc/Timeout.html) and here's a good [article](https://flushentitypacket.github.io/ruby/2015/02/21/ruby-timeout-how-does-it-even-work.html) on how to use it.

Your code would look like this:

```
require 'timeout'
Listing.transaction do
  begin
    Timeout::timeout(1) do
      Delayed::Job.enqueue(RecentListingsJob.new(user.id, @listing.id))
    end
  rescue Timeout::Error
    <whatever you want to happen>
  end
end
```

I don't think there's anything specific on Transactions that allow timeouts, but if you're using Delayed Job, you can look into setting a max_run_time on the worker. Some examples of worker configuration, including max_run_time, from [the docs](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job):

```
# config/initializers/delayed_job_config.rb
Delayed::Worker.destroy_failed_jobs = false
Delayed::Worker.sleep_delay = 60
Delayed::Worker.max_attempts = 3
Delayed::Worker.max_run_time = 5.minutes
Delayed::Worker.read_ahead = 10
Delayed::Worker.default_queue_name = 'default'
Delayed::Worker.delay_jobs = !Rails.env.test?
Delayed::Worker.raise_signal_exceptions = :term
Delayed::Worker.logger = Logger.new(File.join(Rails.root, 'log', 'delayed_job.log'))
```

Comment: i have updated my question. i'd like to avoid ruby's timeout method.

Comment: Updated my answer to add a second option, this time using the Delayed::Job configuration options.